# What are the term names of root equation?

Tags: terminology, roots

In exponentiation we have terms:

$$\text{base}^\text{exponent} = \text{power}.$$

But how the terms are called when dealing with the $n$-th root? For example:

$$\sqrt[n]{x} = z. $$

What are the names of the $n$, $x$, and $z$ terms in this expression?
If there are multiple names, please mention them all if possible.

Comment: $z$ is called the $n$-root of $x$. If $x=1$ one says *$n$-th root of unity*. $n$ is called the *degree* of the root. For more details see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Radicand is the quantity under the root sign, and $n$ is the index; the result is a surd

Comment: I use the term "radicand" as often as I use the word "subtrahend"... which is to say almost never.  That's not to say that its not the most appropriate word for the context... but its certainly not in many people's vocabulary.

Comment: But [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/radicand.html) it is displayed, although I haven't seen it often. There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OokXxiTa4AQ).

Comment: @DietrichBurde nice example, but it's missing the name of result :) edit: oh sorry I see it's called cube root

Comment: The result is a surd - absurd...

Comment: @JMoravitz Perhaps you need to teach more remedial math classes. I use radicand and index quite often while teaching (I need names for the pieces of the expression so that I can cogently speak about them).  That being said, aside form that context, I practically never use these terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression $\sqrt[n]{x} = z$:

- Generally speaking, the term $z$ is an *$n$-th root of $x$*.  The expression itself will typically be defined in context such that it has a unique value, e.g. we will write $\sqrt[3]{8} = 2$ (and not, for example, $-1+i\sqrt{3}$, which also cubes to $8$).  The notation might also indicate the *[principal $n$-th root](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/principal_root) of $x$*.  When $n=2$, we typically simplify the notation and write
  $$ \sqrt{x} = z. $$
  In this case, $z$ is called the *(principal) square root of $x$*.  When $x=1$, $z$ is a *[(principal) root of unity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalRootofUnity.html)*, e.g.
  $$ \sqrt[n]{1} = \text{the principal $n$-th root of unity}. $$
  Roots of unity play a special role in a branch of math called "complex analysis."  One might also see $z$ referred to as a [*surd*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Surd.html).
- The term $x$ is the *[radicand](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radicand.html)*.  Alternatively, if we regard $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}$ a a function, we might refer to $x$ as the *argument* of that function or, perhaps, the *argument of the radical expression*.
- Most often, the $n$ is called the [*index*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radical.html) of the radical.  It may also be referred to as the *degree*.  I have not seen this term in the wild, but a quick search of the interwebs indicates that this is not an uncommon terminology.
- As long as we are giving names to things, the symbol $\sqrt{}$ is called the *radical* or *surd*, and the horizontal line over the radicand is called a [*vinculum*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vinculum.html).  Note that nearly any horizontal bar in mathematics may be called a vinculum (e.g. the horizontal bar in the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ is *also* a vinculum).

Comment: All the answers are great, thank you all for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can call $x$ either the argument or the *radicand* (the thing under the radical sign), and $z$ itself is the $n$th root. The value "$n$" does not have a name.

Comment: Not true. The value "n" certainly has a name, like index or degree.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Both index or degree would signify a power, not a root. So you could say that $n$ is the *reciprocal index* (e.g. if you have cube root, the index/degree is $\frac13$)

Comment: For index, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radical.html)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner good reference!

Answer (score 1):

Radicand is the quantity under the root sign, and $n$ is the index; the result is a surd.

See [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radical.html).